# 'E: Unable to locate package chromium-chromedriver' on rpi

Tags: bash, installation, raspberry-pi, apt, raspberry-pi4

I can't install chromium-chromedriver on my raspberry pi 4.

```bash
$ sudo apt-get install chromium-chromedriver
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package chromium-chromedriver
```

```bash
$ cat sources.list            
deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main contrib non-free
# Additional line for source packages
deb http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates main
```

```bash
$ apt-get search chromedriver
E: Invalid operation search
```

```bash
$ apt search chromedriver      
Sorting... Done
Full Text Search... Done
chromedriver/oldoldstable 72.0.3626.122-1~deb9u1 armhf
  web browser - WebDriver support transitional package

ruby-chromedriver-helper/kali-rolling 2.1.0-7 all
  Easy installation and use of chromedriver
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Kali rolling is based on the latest stable version of Debian, which is currently Debian 11. The version of chromium-chromedriver that is compatible with Kali rolling is available from the default software repositories of Ubuntu 21.10 which is also based on Debian 11. To install chromium-chromedriver in Kali Linux open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt update
wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/universe/c/chromium-browser/chromium-chromedriver_85.0.4183.83-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb
sudo apt install ./chromium-chromedriver_85.0.4183.83-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb
```